# Youtube video as background on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube

I'd like to use a youtube video sequence as a background on my landing page.
I want the video to be muted and use only a minute of it. It's an existing youtube video(from a friend).

- How could I do to make it responsive? (with youtube when I resize I have the big black borders)
- How to mute the sound, and loop?

I believe I'd need some JS... but I don't know anything in JS... If someone could explain.

```
.video-background
  iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iUBn-nipNkk?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;start=245&amp;autoplay=1&amp;&loop=1" frameborder="0"

.container.main-title
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.text-center
        h1.text-inverse
          | Mark Knopfler
        p.text-inverse
          | Mark in summer long ago
        br
        br
        =link_to root_path(@root, anchor: "about") do
          i.fa.fa-4x.fa-arrow-down.fa-fw.hub.text-inverse

.section
  .container
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-5
        =image_tag("mains/band.png", class:'band')
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-7#about
        br
        h2.text-primary  About the website
        p.site-description "Mark In Summer Long AgoVestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem."

.section
  .container
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12
      h1.text-center.text-primary MK & me... somehow...
      br
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          = link_to page_path('concerts/index') do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/concerts.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title Concerts
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          = link_to page_path('calendars/index') do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/calendars.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title Calendars
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          = link_to page_path("events/index") do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/events.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title Other events

.section
  .container
    .col-md-12
      h1.text-center.text-primary Related Mark Knopfler websites
      br
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          = link_to "http://www.markknopfler.com/" do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/mkcom.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title Official MK Website
              p.section-description MK.com
              p.section-description Visit the very official MK website, tour dates, shop, annoucements...

      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          =link_to  "http://www.guyfletcher.co.uk/"  do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/gf.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title Guy Fletcher 
              p.section-description A very intersting Website to keep in your favorites.
              p.section-description Guy Fletcher runs here a forum, studio and tour diaries ! Have a look !

      .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-4.under-section
        .make-it-slow
          = link_to "http://www.amarkintime.org/forum/" do
            .thumbnail
              = image_tag("mains/forum.jpg", class:"category")
              h3.section-title AMIT forum
              p.section-description A very nice place to exchange with fans from all over the world! This a non official forum. 
              p.section-description Be cool and do not moan !
```

with some sass

```
.video-background iframe
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  pointer-events: none
  filter: grayscale(80%)
  z-index: -99

.main-title
  margin-top: 15%
  height: 80%
  color: #ffffff
  h1
    font-size: 60px
  p
    font-size: 30px
```

[image]

Comment: There's no video nor is there an iframe on your site. In your application.js manifest it has jQuery and Bootstrap plugins. Yet you added another copy of jQuery and Bootstrap to load. You have scripts loading before your stylesheets. You have `<link>`s in the body as well as a `<script>` at the top area of the body. In this `<script>` block it's trying to initiate a carousel plugin to an element that doesn't exist. Btw you have one `<script>` tag misspelled as `<scrip>`.

Comment: There is no video yet I know this. I put the exemple of my current site to show where I want to add the video ( instead of the van image)...
I will check for the script thanks

Comment: Check my iFrameless/JS/CSS only solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616179/youtube-video-header-background/45377998#45377998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help and it's actually faster than trying youtube...

I gave up the youtube video because I couldn't remove the black border and that was really annoying.
So I've downloaded the video, cut the sequence I needed in iMovie, muted the sound and upload the video on AWS.

I did this:

```
.cover
  =video_tag(["https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/markinsum/MKlanding.mp4"], autoplay:true, loop:true, class:"landing-video")
```

and my Sass:

```
.landing-video
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  filter: grayscale(80%)
  z-index: 1
  min-width: 100%
  min-height: 100%
```

The result is [here](http://www.markinsummerlongago.com/), It has to be improved  btw

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has very little to do with what you want to do with YouTube (with `.video-background` being the exception). Please just test this Snippet on a webpage with your video and **without** all of that other stuff first. Try locating the actual YT Player in your source and take care of what you cut and where you paste.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>YouTube FS/Mute</title>

  <style>
    .frame {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <section class="frame">
    <iframe id='player' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o0u4M6vppCI?&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

  </section>
  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>


  <script>
    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        playerVars: {
          'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 0,
          'autohide': 1,
          'wmode': 'opaque',
          'showinfo': 0,
          'loop': 1,
          'mute': 1
        },
        videoId: 'o0u4M6vppCI',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
      });

    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.mute()
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry it doesn'td o what I want... have a look on my edit, i believe i wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a full background iframe life this:

```
<iframe id="myVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myvideo;autoplay=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

1. The background on 100% should make it responsive.
2. To mute the sound you will need some javascript. The 'autoplay=1' will make it autoplay and loop.

Create a js file and add this jQuery bit:

```
var myVideo =  iframe.getElementById('myVideo'); 
myVideo.mute();
```

Change 'myVideo' with the id you choose on the iframe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the JQuery bit in my appication.js and added the id to my ifram like so  `iframe#myVideo src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iUBn-nipNkk?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;start=245&amp;autoplay=1&amp;&loop=1" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"`
_it's slim not html_ btw it doesnt change anything :(